# Computing the minimum of this loss function

Tags: optimization, logarithms

I encountered an interesting paper with the following loss function:

> [image]

Now they say in the paper that the minimum with respect to the right hand sight with respect to $\sigma^2$ can be obtained by setting $\sigma^2$ to $|\hat{y}_i-y_i|$. My math is a bit rusty, can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: What is the article ?

Comment: Anyway you simply have to evaluate the derivative with respect to $\sigma_i$ and putting it to zero. Where do you find difficulties ?

Comment: https://research.fb.com/publications/correlated-uncertainty-for-learning-dense-correspondences-from-noisy-labels/ is the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the derivative with respect to $\sigma_i^2$ on the RHS and equate this to 0. The derivative is equal to:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \sigma_i^2} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2} -
\frac{(\hat{y}_i - y)^2}{\sigma_i^4}\right).
\end{align*}
Now equating this to 0 yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2} = \frac{(\hat{y}_i - y)^2}{\sigma_i^4}
\end{align*}
which implies $\sigma_i^2 = (\hat{y}_i - y)^2$ and thus $\sigma_i = |\hat{y}_i - y|$.

Comment: I see it, thanks